# How to create a fluent chaining equation solver that can work `one().plus().two().equalTo()`

Tags: javascript, this, new-operator

I have been given a task at my internship , I have to create math operations like `plus()`, `minus()` etc. using this and new keywords.

example: `one().plus().two().equalTo()` , given line of code must return `3`.

I tried creating functions which returns values.

```
function one(){
    return 1;
}
```

But I am not able to figure out how `plus()` and `equalTo()` will work.

Comment: Well you can't simply return 1; you have to return an object that has access to a `plus()` method, etc.

Comment: I am just getting started with this whole js ecosystem, no prior experience as well. Can you help me out with this problem statement?

Comment: What you've got is a fairly big project; it's too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. You need a family of "starter" functions (like `one()` in your example), and then a scheme for how the chainable functions will work.

Comment: I understand, Can you help me out with this line only `one.plus.two.equalsTo` , it must return 3. I will try to figure out rest of the functions. once I get idea about how the above code works, I believe it'll be doable further. Thanks

Comment: What happens when it is used like one().two().equalTo()? Or plus().two().equalTo()

Comment: What if you want to add 217 to something?

Comment: Is this really related to both `this` and `new`? The title and the tags mention these, yet the body doesn't. And you can easily implement such a fluent interface without using either. Even if it *has to* use both `this` and `new` the title is not at all descriptive about what the question is. I'd suggest at the very least amending the title to summarise the real question. And maybe think whether you really want the question to be constrained by these two concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using function chaining:

```js
const numbering = (fn, n) => () => fn?.(n) ?? n;

function one() {
  this._fn = numbering(this._fn, 1);
  return this;
}

function two() {
  this._fn = numbering(this._fn, 2);
  return this;
}

function plus() {
  const fn = this._fn;
  this._fn = n => (fn?.() ?? 0) + n;
  return this;
}

function equalTo() {
  const fn = this._fn;
  delete this._fn;
  return fn?.() ?? 0;
}


console.log(one().plus().two().equalTo());                // 3
console.log(one().plus().two().plus().two().equalTo());   // 5
```

Comment: That is doing exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man

Comment: can you please explain the use of so many ternary operators in the code>? specifically ` this.fn = n => (fn?.() ?? 0) * n;` this line.

Comment: @Tejdoshi It’s not ternary operator but [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). In short it means if `fn` exists, call it,  otherwise fallback to `0`

Comment: Okay I got it. Can you please explain `function equalTo() {
  const fn = this.fn;
  delete this.fn;
  return fn?.() ?? 0;
}` , why delete is being used here.?

Comment: It deletes `this._fn` from `this`(`window` in this case) to clear the accumulated function `this._fn` after calling `equalTo()`, and then get the result from it. So it won't affect the next accumulation. You don't have to do it if you're only calling it once.

Comment: I understand. Thankyou so much for such an eloquent explanation. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Such an interface can be implemented as mutually dependant classes one for operands like `one()` and `two()`, etc., another for operations like `plus()`, `equalTo()`, etc. This ensures that the chain cannot contain invalid sequences like `one().plus().plus()` or `one().one().two()`. Operands can only be followed by operations and vice versa.

```js
class Operands {
  constructor(nextOperation) {
    this.nextOperation = nextOperation;
  }
  
  one() { return new Operations(this.nextOperation(1)); }
  two() { return new Operations(this.nextOperation(2)); }
};

class Operations {
  constructor (total) {
    this.total = total;
  }
  
  plus()    { return new Operands(nextNumber => this.total + nextNumber); }
  equalTo() { return this.total; }
};

const one = () => new Operations(1);
const two = () => new Operations(2);

console.log(one().plus().two().equalTo());                // 3
console.log(one().plus().two().plus().two().equalTo());   // 5
```

The `Operations` class is initialised with a number maintaining the total, while `Operands` is given the *next* operation to execute. This allows
`one().plus().two()` to work by passing the operation and the current total from `plus()` to the next operand. Essentially `one().plus()`this looks like `1 + _` which when followed with `two()`  fills in the gap and resolves the operation at that step carrying forward the total which is `3` and it's for the next operation to be selected for that number.

Since a new object is created at each step, this means the total and the intermediate steps are is maintained at any point in the chain. This allows for breaking the chain and still maintaining total that would not get mutated from other operations:

```
console.log("(1 + 2) + 1 + 1 =", 
  onePlusTwo.plus().one().plus().one().equalTo()); // 5
console.log("(1 + 2) + 2 =", 
  onePlusTwo.plus().two().equalTo());              // 5
console.log("(1 + 2) =", 
  onePlusTwo.equalTo());                           // 3

const twoPlus = two().plus();

console.log("(2 + ) 1 =", 
  twoPlus.one().equalTo()); // 3
console.log("(2 + ) 2 =", 
  twoPlus.two().equalTo()); // 4
```

```js
class Operands {
  constructor(nextOperation) {
    this.nextOperation = nextOperation;
  }
  
  one() { return new Operations(this.nextOperation(1)); }
  two() { return new Operations(this.nextOperation(2)); }
};

class Operations {
  constructor (total) {
    this.total = total;
  }
  
  plus()    { return new Operands(nextNumber => this.total + nextNumber); }
  equalTo() { return this.total; }
};

const one = () => new Operations(1);
const two = () => new Operations(2);

const onePlusTwo = one().plus().two();

console.log("(1 + 2) + 1 + 1 =", 
  onePlusTwo.plus().one().plus().one().equalTo()); // 5
console.log("(1 + 2) + 2 =", 
  onePlusTwo.plus().two().equalTo());              // 5
console.log("(1 + 2) =", 
  onePlusTwo.equalTo());                           // 3

const twoPlus = two().plus();

console.log("(2 + ) 1 =", 
  twoPlus.one().equalTo()); // 3
console.log("(2 + ) 2 =", 
  twoPlus.two().equalTo()); // 4
```

The same concept can be implemented using only functions without using `new` or `this`

```js
const operands = (nextOperation) => ({
    one: () => operations(nextOperation(1))
  , two: () => operations(nextOperation(2))
});

const operations = (total) => ({
    plus   : () => operands(nextNumber => total + nextNumber)
  , equalTo: () => total
});

//initialise an "empty" operand which will choose the initial value based on 
//calling `one()` or `two()` 
const init = operands(n => n);

const one = init.one;
const two = init.two;

console.log(one().plus().two().equalTo());                // 3
console.log(one().plus().two().plus().two().equalTo());   // 5
```

---

Right now while code like `one().plus().plus()` or `one().one().two()` the error message is not going to be very helpful. To get better error messages, each object/class can implement the methods from the other one and throw errors for those. Which will allow more expressive error handling

Using classes:

```js
class Operands {
  constructor(nextOperation) {
    this.nextOperation = nextOperation;
  }
  
  one() { return new Operations(this.nextOperation(1)); }
  two() { return new Operations(this.nextOperation(2)); }
  
  plus()    { throw new Error("Operation plus cannot be used in this position"); }
  equalTo() { throw new Error("Operation equalTo cannot be used in this position"); }
};

class Operations {
  constructor (total) {
    this.total = total;
  }
  
  plus()    { return new Operands(nextNumber => this.total + nextNumber); }
  equalTo() { return this.total; }
  
  one() { throw new Error("Operand one cannot be used in this position"); }
  two() { throw new Error("Operand two cannot be used in this position"); }
};

const one = () => new Operations(1);
const two = () => new Operations(2);

try {
  console.log("1 + + =", one().plus().plus());
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error with 1 + +:", error.message);
}

try {
  console.log("1 1 2 =", one().one().two());
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error with 1 1 2:", error.message);
}
```

Using functions:

```js
const operands = (nextOperation) => ({
    one: () => operations(nextOperation(1))
  , two: () => operations(nextOperation(2))
  
  , plus: () => { throw new Error("Operation plus cannot be used in this position"); }
  , equalTo: () => { throw new Error("Operation equalTo cannot be used in this position"); }
});

const operations = (total) => ({
    plus   : () => operands(nextNumber => total + nextNumber)
  , equalTo: () => total
  
  , one: () => { throw new Error("Operand one cannot be used in this position") }
  , two: () => { throw new Error("Operand two cannot be used in this position") }
});
  
const init = operands(n => n);

const one = init.one;
const two = init.two;

try {
  console.log("1 + + =", one().plus().plus());
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error with 1 + +:", error.message);
}

try {
  console.log("1 1 2 =", one().one().two());
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error with 1 1 2:", error.message);
}
```